# Optaplanner: Calculate Score of a given Schedule with Drools

Tags: optaplanner

I am going to build a FlowShop with Optaplanner and i have to calculate the Score for a given Schedule. 
Is it possible to calculate the Score for a given Schedule with drools or do i have to use a EasyScoreCalculator instead?
With EasyScoreCalculator.calculate(Schedule) it is quite easy to get the Score of a certain Schedule but i have not found a way to get it calculated by drools and asking if that is even possible.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`EasyScoreCalculator` is an alternative to `scoreDRL` (= drools) and/or `ConstraintProvider` (uses drools under the hood). Those latter two are incremental, which mean they scale better. If you don't need to scale, you don't need to use them.

You can use `<assertionScoreDirectorFactory>` (see docs) to verify that your EasyScoreCalculator returns the same result as `scoreDRL` or `ConstraintProvider`.

But with `ConstraintProvider`, you can also just use `ConstraintVerifier` to unit test your constraint easily and quickly.

Comment: ah ok. But does there exists a method for scoreDRL where i can commit a certain schedule to get the score of it back. Like i got a schedule from a company and i have to compare it with schedules i got from optimizations.

Comment: yes, there does. Look for `<assertionScoreDirectorFactory>` in the docs. That will not just check it once, but for every score that OptaPlanner calculates.